# input to database successfully but still always give a fail alert jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to input data from a input form to database, but it always gives a fail alert even the data is success to input. so this is the part of my code

jquery

```
$("#daftar").click(function(){
    nim = $("#kdAlumni").val();
    tahun = $("#kdTahun").val();
    nama = $("#Nama").val();
    nohp = $("#Nohp").val();
    foto = $("#Foto").val();
    email = $("#Email").val();
    jurusan = $("#kdJurusan").val();
    judul = $("#judul").val();
    fakultas = $("#kdFakultas").val();
    tgl = $("#Lahir").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "insertupdate.php",
        data: "nim=" + nim + "&nama=" + nama + "&nohp=" + nohp + "&email=" + email + "&jurusan=" + jurusan + "&foto=" + foto + "&judul=" + judul + "&fakultas=" + fakultas + "&tahun=" + tahun + "&tgl=" + tgl,
        success: function(dat)
        {
            if(dat == 'true')
            {
                alert("input success");
                $("#kdAlumni").val("");
                $("#kdTahun").val("");
                $("#Nama").val("");
                $("#Nohp").val("");
                $("#Foto").val("");
                $("#Email").val("");
                $("#kdJurusan").val("");
                $("#judul").val("");
                $("#kdFakultas").val("");
                $("#Lahir").val("");
            }
            else if(dat == 'false')
            {
                alert("input fail");
                $("#kdAlumni").val("");
                $("#kdTahun").val("");
                $("#Nama").val("");
                $("#Nohp").val("");
                $("#Foto").val("");
                $("#Email").val("");
                $("#kdJurusan").val("");
                $("#judul").val("");
                $("#kdFakultas").val("");
                $("#Lahir").val("");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

php

```
<?php 
session_start();
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$pass = "";
$name = "buku_tahunan";

$koneksi = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$pass,$name);

if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    die("koneksi DB Gagal".mysqli_connect_error());
}

$nim = $_POST["nim"];
$nama = $_POST["nama"];
$nohp = $_POST["nohp"];
$email = $_POST["email"];
$jurusan = $_POST["jurusan"];
$fotoN = $_FILES['foto']['name'];
$fotoT = $_FILES['foto']['tmp_name'];
$tujuan = "foto/" .$fotoN;
$judul = $_POST['judul'];
$fakultas = $_POST["fakultas"];
$tahun = $_POST["tahun"];
$tgl = $_POST["tgl"];


$sql="INSERT INTO `data_alumni`(`kdAlumni`, `nama`, `noHP`, `email`, `foto`, `judulSkripsi`, `kdFakultas`, `kdTahun`, `kdJurusan`, `tgl_lahir`) VALUES ('$nim','$nama','$nohp','$email','$tujuan','$judul','$fakultas','$tahun','$jurusan','$tgl')";
$insert = mysqli_query($koneksi,$sql);
move_uploaded_file($sumber, $tujuan);
if($insert)
{
    echo 'true';
}
else
{
    echo 'false';
}
?>
```

that's all of my code to input data to database, so what's the real problem from my code? thank you

Comment: In you javascript, try and log the value of data and see what it returns. Then you can adjust your code according. Alternatively, you can return a Json object from php and working with it in your javascript

Comment: @Jan sebastian are you sure that all the data inserted to database??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I realize the reason of this error, when I try to debug the script I see the problem that caused by $_FILES. The way that I input value from  in javascript is the real problems

Answer (score 0):

It's not uncommon to have extra whitespace in the response. Try trimming any whitespace:

```
success: function(dat){

   dat = dat.trim();

   if(dat == 'true'){.....
```

Also check what `dat` is in the response to be sure it is what is expected and to narrow down where the actual issue lies.

Generally easier to use json for all responses

Comment: Add some error handling in both ends then and find out what the errors are and where